# How can we set email configuratoin in AppControoler in cakePHP?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I want to overwrite email configuration setting in App Controller in cakephp, my email server setting stored in database and admin has rights to change these setting any time so I need to update these setting dynamically in my app. My App Controller code is bellow:

```
<?php
class AppController extends Controller {
public $helpers = array('Front','Custom','Js'=>array('Jquery','MooTools'));
public $components = array(
'Security' => array(
'blackHoleCallback' => 'blackhole',
'csrfUseOnce' => false
),
'Session','Email',
'Auth','Cookie',
'Facebook.Connect' => array('model' => 'User'),'Custom','RequestHandler'
);
public function beforeFilter()
{
parent::beforeFilter();
//Admin Settings
foreach($this->Custom->getSettings() as $key=>$val):
Configure::write("Adminsetting.".$key,$val);
endforeach;
// End Admin Setting
$siteconf=Configure :: read('Adminsetting');
/* Email Server Setting */
//if($siteconf['transport']=='Smtp'){
$this->Email->delivery='Smtp';
$this->Email->smtpOptions=array(
'port'=>$siteconf['port'],
'timeout'=>$siteconf['timeout'],
'host' => $siteconf['hostname'],
'username'=>$siteconf['username'],
'password'=>$siteconf['password']
);
.....
?>

When I using $this->Email->sent() I am getting this error:
"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."
Please suggest...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your email configuration settings are in /app/Config/email.php. 
At anytime before sending any new email, you override and set your default email parameters.

What I suggest would be to handle your custom email settings in a settings table (and create the appropriate controller and model and views either through the bake command line or by following the blog tutorial).

Your table could follow the following schema :

```
CREATE TABLE `settings` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `key` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

Then load all your settings in the beforeFilter() callback of your AppController class.
You could do something like this:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Setting = ClassRegistry::init('Setting');
    $settings = $this->Setting->find('list', array('fields' => array('key' => 'value')));
    foreach($settings as $key => $value) {
        Configure::write($key, $value);
    }
}
```

With basic CRUD operations you can now manage any settings.

Now when you want to send an email you should adjust your code like this somehow:

```
$Email = new CakeEmail();
$Email->template('welcome', 'fancy')
    ->emailFormat(Configure::read('emailFormat'))
    ->to('bob@example.com')
    ->from('app@domain.com')
    ->transport(Configure::read('transport'))
    ->host(Configure::read('host'))
    ->port(Configure::read('port'))
    ->username(Configure::read('username'))
    ->password(Configure::read('password'))
    ->send();
```

**Be warned. This should answer your issue but that's not what I would personally do because now any existing setting could be overridden and that 's extremely dangerous.**

Comment: This is not what i exactly need, I want to change values these variables of email in app controllers... 

->transport(Configure::read('transport'))
->host(Configure::read('host'))
->port(Configure::read('port'))
->username(Configure::read('username'))
->password(Configure::read('password'))